# Is it safe to use vegetables (e.g. Romaine lettuce) that may be contaminated with E. coli if they are fully cooked?

Tags: food-safety

I strongly suspect the answer is **no**, but I feel like there should be a question here about this for people to find more detailed information about as these outbreaks become more common.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I have read, some strains of E. Coli are heat-resistant, so it's not a good idea to think that cooking it will kill the bacteria if present. Also, you might contaminate your cooking utensils or other surfaces that do not encounter the heat. It's safest to just get rid of it.

Comment: Plus cooked lettuce = yuck

Comment: @GdD Well, there was an article (since pulled, and AIUI the current outbreak is of a heat-resistant strain) suggesting making stir fry with it or something, that's what made me think of this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with Romaine Lettuce (specifically) is that the vast majority of people eat it raw. That is why the U.S. CDC was so fast to put out an [E. Coli alert, Nov 26th](https://www.cdc.gov/ecoli/2018/o157h7-11-18/index.html) telling people to throw away any/all the Romaine you had. The illness was popping up, but the CDC couldn't pinpoint the origin of the tainted lettuce. Their swift alert prevented (possibly) 100's of deaths. Fortunately, [E. Coli Prevention](https://www.cdc.gov/ecoli/ecoli-prevention.html) is relatively simple (handwashing, cooking thoroughly, avoid cross contamination, etc.). And for now... don't eat the Romaine.